# Tab button skips alwas one input - Angular 11

Tags: html, angular

I have a trivial problem - TAB skips always one input when pressed
(I don't use "tabindex" property). When I press TAB button, browser focus goes FROM 'A' to 'C', then from 'C' to 'E' etc. When I change focus manually (using mouseclick) on input "i+1", it skips those inputs which were previously working.

I am using Angular 11. Here is code:

```
<p-dialog header="xxx" [(visible)]="displayModal" [modal]="true" [style]="{width: '65vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000"
           >
    <div>
            <label>A</label> <div><input  type="text" pInputText /></div>
            <label>B</label> <div><input  type="text" pInputText/></div>
            <label>C</label> <div><input  type="text" pInputText /></div>
            <label>D</label> <div><input  type="text" pInputText /></div>
            <label>E</label><div><input  type="text" pInputText /></div>
            <label>F</label><div> <input  type="text" pInputText /></div>        
    </div>

</p-dialog>
```

This code is put inside p-dialog which is located in another p-dialog.
I don't have these kind of problems in any other part of my project.

Comment: I would first recommend you use the attribute `for` for the HTML5 label element, get the `input` out of the `div` element wrapper and try again. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#using_the_for_attribute this is entirely aimed to resolve accessibility concerns

Comment: Probably you somewhere have JS reacting to pressing TAB, so you have normal one and a JS one at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem and I have tried multiple fixes ( like tabindex and removing the container in which the inputs are placed ), however those did not help.

I have however managed to fix the issue by **not nesting** the `p-dialog` ( it seems to be a problem from the **PrimeNG dialog** ).

You should take the `p-dialog` outside of the other `p-dialog` if possible. That fixed it for me.